# Changing Tkinter Treeview column to only show date, not time

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, tkinter

I have a Tkinter treeview which is populated by data from an SQLite3 table from a separate file. The date column comes from an Excel spreadsheet but the column in Excel is text, so I figured that it should import to the SQLite table as a string.

However, when the treeview is displayed, it displays in the format of date-time instead of just being the date. I am not sure why this is. I assume I need to use date() to retrieve the date part of the DateTime value but where do I do that?

I have added the code which populates my treeview. I think the solution is about editing the last line with the table insert to pick up whether a value is a DateTime value and change it to just a date with date().

[My column where I need just the date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An3Yy.png)

```
rowNum = len(observationList)
columns = ("species", "location", "x", "y", "time", "date", "temperature", "humidity", "user", "#")
table = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=columns, show="headings", height=30)
for col in columns:
     table.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: treeviewSort(table, _col, False))
for i in range(rowNum): table.insert("", END, values=(observationList[I]))
```

Comment: How can we help without your code?

Comment: I am sort of unsure what code you'd need. I'll edit with any possible relevant code snippets I can now.

Comment: Have you checked the content in SQLite3 table? I have tested with a sample table having a column of type `datetime` and get a string if the content in the table have just the date part.  Basically I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oh, I have the type as text. I was under the impression that the type for date-times had to be text, integer or real. I'll see if I can edit it to be type datetime. I'm wondering if Excel is somehow passing time despite my Excel column being text with just the date.

Comment: So, I just edited my date column in my table creation to date datetime instead of date text and I am still getting the issue. That must mean that Excel is giving the SQLite3 table time data somehow. I'm gonna mess around with the Excel data and see if I can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, the way I fixed it was setting the Excel column with the date data as text with just the date. I then used date datetime in the SQLite3 table creation instead of date text and this has fixed it.

A massive thank you to [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) for suggesting a change of datatype in the SQLite3 table.